# Installing PostgreSQL ODBC driver on windows 10

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, odbc

I'm looking for the simplest way for Access users to connect to a PostgreSQL database. We will use it as a simple interface for updating data.

My idea was to create an Access database with linked tables to the PostgreSQL database, and to use a file based dsn connection so that the users don't have to set up their own machine connections.

I can set up a file based connection if I install the official driver (the 32-bit works for me), and *IF* I have the PostgreSQL database software installed as well. If I only install the odbc-drivers, I cannot create or use a file based connection, only machine based connections. It says it cannot verify the connection.

Is this intended?

I would rather not have to make the users install the whole database software, just to be able to connect (remotely) through Access.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.6. on a ubuntu server, and Windows 10. Have tried installing both 32 and 64 bit odbc drivers (https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/msi/psqlodbc_09_06_0500-x86.zip, https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/msi/psqlodbc_09_06_0500-x64.zip)

Thanks for any info or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Installing the psqlodbc driver packaged by Enterprise DB works (https://www.enterprisedb.com/software-downloads-postgres). I had installed the whole PostgreSQL package from there before, that's why I thought the whole package was needed. It turns out only their driver is needed to make it work. For some reason, their driver works while the official driver from https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/ does not. For information, when you install the standard PostgreSQL package from EDB, you get the option of also installing the odbc driver. You can then install a 32-bit version in exe format which then can be installed on the other users computers (without having to create a user profile on EDBD)

Comment: If you have a solution, then put it in the answer, *not* in the question. Self-answering is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Yup, that looks better. Done.

Comment: Looking forward to after the two days grace period is up. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I Download the driver from:
https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

Search your PG version and install it, then check you ODBC drives under administratives tools.

have a nice day

Comment: where can i get odbc driver for PostgreSQL13 ?